# Installing font in AIX and Listing out already installed fonts in AIX

Tags: aix, fonts, fontconfig

1) How can I install fonts in AIX?

Below are the fonts I want to install:

1. MS Sans Serif
2. Arial
3. Times New Roman
4. Courier New

2) How can I list out installed fonts in AIX?

**OS Level:**

```
bash-4.3$ oslevel -s
7100-04-01-1543
```

My requirement is to convert RTF to PDF (in servers which runs on AIX)
Since some fonts are not installed, my converted PDF looks unaligned.

Answer (score 1):

To list all available fonts you can use command [xlsfonts](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds6/xlsfonts.htm)

If you want to add fonts you can put them in some directory and use command [xset](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds6/xset.htm)

Check for option -fp on xset comment